# certbot SSL certifact stops working on nginx configuration update

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a **Django** application setup CI/CD via Bitbucket on AWS EC2 via AWS CodeDeploy.

In the AWS CodeDeploy hooks under **AfterInstall**

```
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/ngnix.sh
      timeout: 6000
      runas: ubuntu
```

and the **nginx.sh** script is

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mkdir -p /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
mkdir -p /etc/nginx/sites-available
sudo mkdir -p /etc/nginx/log/
sudo unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*
sudo cp /path_to_app/configs/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/app-host.conf
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/app-host.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/app-host.conf
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx status
```

But every time this script is run via CI/CD pipeline, SSL stops working and the website is not accessible using **https**.

To re-enable SSL, I have to manually run

```
sudo certbot --nginx
```

And re-configure SSL certificate.

**What could be the issue for not working of the `SSL` and how to automate this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certbot procures the ssl certificates from Lets Encrypt and keeps those certificates on your machine. You can run the command `sudo certbot certificates` to see the certificates path.

```
Found the following certs:
  Certificate Name: example.com
    Domains: example.com, www.example.com
    Expiry Date: 2017-02-19 19:53:00+00:00 (VALID: 30 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
```

You need to store the the files located at `Certificate Path` & `Private Key Path` in a persisted volume so they don't get wiped out everytime you deploy your app. In your case I think these certificate files are getting wiped out and that is the reason you have to run the command `sudo certbot --nginx` to procure new cerificate.